# How to add array items in this kind of code?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to generate an equivalent of the following using MySql PHP.

The raw PHP looks like this:

```
$array['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array(v=>'Concept-1'), array('v'=>3.28),array('v'=>4.28),array('v'=>5.28)) );
$array['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array(v=>'Concept-2'), array('v'=>1.28),array('v'=>1.28),array('v'=>4.28)) );
$array['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array(v=>'Concept-3'), array('v'=>5.68),array('v'=>6.45),array('v'=>1.58)) );
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to generate an equivalent code dynamically.

So I tried (There are 6 rows):

```
for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    ${"temp$i"} = array();
    foreach ($alltheraces as $key => $value){
      $t = $alltheraces[$key][$i][1];
      array_push(${"temp$i"}, $t);
    }
    $array['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array(v=>'Concept-'),${"temp$i"}));
  }
  echo json_encode($array);
```

But the problem now is the $temp is an array, hence my Jason output looks like this, the 'v''s are missing. I haven't used object oriented PHP before so kind of stuck here figuring out what to do :( :

```
rows: [
    {
    c: [
    {
      v: "Concept-"
    },
    [
      2.8775,
      3.11,
      2.91,
      1.77,
      3.3
    ]
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    ${"temp$i"} = array();
    array_push(${"temp$i"}, array(v=>"Concept-$i"));
    $st="Concept-$i";
    foreach ($alltheraces as $key => $value){
      $t = array(v=>$alltheraces[$key][$i][1]);
      array_push(${"temp$i"}, $t);
      $st .= ",".$alltheraces[$key][$i][1];
    }
    $array['rows'][] = array('c' => ${"temp$i"});
    array_push($data, $st);

  }
```